# How to get percentage of categorical variables and overall percent of a single choice

Tags: r

Basically I have a new data as below and I want the percentage of yes in each province likewise percentage of no each province and I want overall percentage of Yes and No.

```
new_data <-data.frame(province=c("a","b"),food=c("yes","no","no","yes","yes","no"),shelter_type=c("unfinished","permanent","transitional"))
```

and I want output as below

```
out_put <- data.frame (province=c("a","b","overall_perc"),food_yes_per=c(66.6,36.4,50),food_No_per=c(36.4,66.6,50),shelter_type_unfinished=c(50,50,33.3),shelter_type_permanent=c(50,50,33.3),shelter_type_transitional=c(50,50,33.3))
```

can anyone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer

The tricky part of this problem is the difference between row percentages and column percentages that are represented in the data. Since all rows but the total row are column percentages, we will need to process the data twice, first for the the `province` * `variable` level of aggregation, and then `variable` aggregated over `province`.

```
new_data <-data.frame(province=c("a","b"),
                      food=c("yes","no","no","yes","yes","no"),
                      shelter_type=c("unfinished","permanent","transitional"))   
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

First we'll generate what ultimately becomes column percentages within a wide format data frame. We use `pivot_longer()` to create a narrow format tidy data set, create counts, `summarise()` the counts, and then `group_by()` variable & value to generate column percentages.

```
new_data  %>% group_by(province) %>%
     pivot_longer(.,c(food,shelter_type),names_to = "variable",
                  values_to = "value") %>% ungroup() %>%
     group_by(province,variable,value) %>% 
     mutate(count = 1) %>% summarise(.,count = sum(count)) %>% ungroup() %>%
     group_by(variable,value) %>% 
     mutate(pct = count / sum(count)) -> prov_var
```

Next, we reaggregate the data to create what will become the `Total` province. We take the original data, convert to narrow format tidy data, and this time `group_by()` variable & value to calculate the percentages across `province`.

```
new_data  %>% group_by(province) %>%
     pivot_longer(.,c(food,shelter_type),names_to = "variable",
                  values_to = "value") %>% ungroup() %>%
     group_by(variable,value) %>%  
     mutate(count = 1) %>% summarise(., count = sum(count)) %>% 
     mutate(province = "Total",
            pct = count / sum(count)) -> tot_var
```

Finally, we `rbind()` the data and use `tidyr::pivot_wider()` to create the wide format data frame as illustrated in the original question.

```
# now add rows & pivot_wider()
rbind(prov_var,tot_var) %>% 
     mutate(concat_var = paste(variable,value,sep="_")) %>% 
     select(-variable,-value,-count) %>% 
     pivot_wider(id_cols = province,names_from=concat_var,
                 values_from = pct)
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  province food_no food_yes shelter_type_perm… shelter_type_tra… shelter_type_unf…
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>
1 a          0.333    0.667              0.5               0.5               0.5  
2 b          0.667    0.333              0.5               0.5               0.5  
3 Total      0.5      0.5                0.333             0.333             0.333
```

### Partial solutions with `tables::tabular()`

Another way to attempt to answer the question is with the `tables` package. We can generate the column percentages by `province` as follows.

```
library(tables)

# replicate column percentages, where "All" is 100

tabular((Factor(province,"Province") + 1) ~ 
                (Factor(food) + Factor(shelter_type)) * 
                (Percent("col")),data = new_data )
```

Unfortunately, the row for totals isn't what was requested.

```
          food            shelter_type                        
          no      yes     permanent    transitional unfinished
 Province Percent Percent Percent      Percent      Percent   
 a         33.33   66.67   50           50           50       
 b         66.67   33.33   50           50           50       
 All      100.00  100.00  100          100          100
```

We can fix the `All` row by configuring the table with row percentages, but then the data by province doesn't match what was requested.

```
# replicate row percentages in All row
tabular((Factor(province,"Province") + 1) ~ 
                (Factor(food) + Factor(shelter_type)) * 
                (Percent("row")),data = new_data )

          food            shelter_type                        
          no      yes     permanent    transitional unfinished
 Province Percent Percent Percent      Percent      Percent   
 a        33.33   66.67   33.33        33.33        33.33     
 b        66.67   33.33   33.33        33.33        33.33     
 All      50.00   50.00   33.33        33.33        33.33
```

### Correct solution with `tabular()`

However, if we control the percentages by specifying them on the row dimension of the table instead of the column dimension, we can achieve the desired output.

```
tabular((Factor(province,"Province")*( colPct = Percent("col")) + 1*(rowPct = Percent("row")))  ~ 
                (Factor(food) + Factor(shelter_type)),data = new_data )
```

...and the output:

```
                 food        shelter_type                        
 Province        no    yes   permanent    transitional unfinished
 a        colPct 33.33 66.67 50.00        50.00        50.00     
 b        colPct 66.67 33.33 50.00        50.00        50.00     
 All      rowPct 50.00 50.00 33.33        33.33        33.33
```

### Original answer

We'll use the `dplyr` package to summarise the data by province & food, calculate percentages, and then `ungroup()` to calculate percentage of total responses.

```
new_data <-data.frame(province=c("a","b"),
                      food=c("yes","no","no","yes","yes","no"),
                      shelter_type=c("unfinished","permanent","transitional"))

library(dplyr)

new_data %>% group_by(province,food) %>%
     summarise(count_food = n()) %>% group_by(province) %>%
     mutate(pct_food = count_food / sum(count_food)) %>%
     ungroup(.) %>%
     mutate(pct_total = count_food / sum(count_food))
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  province food  count_food pct_food pct_total
  <chr>    <chr>      <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a        no             1    0.333     0.167
2 a        yes            2    0.667     0.333
3 b        no             2    0.667     0.333
4 b        yes            1    0.333     0.167
>
```

Comment: this is  a good answer but I want shelter_type and there is much more variables as well but I want ouptput in below format:
```
out_put <- data.frame (province=c("a","b","overall_perc"),food_yes_per=c(66.6,33.3,50),food_No_per=c(33.4,66.6,50),shelter_type_unfinished=c(50,50,33.3),shelter_type_permanent=c(50,50,33.3),shelter_type_transitional=c(50,50,33.3))
```
Thank you

Comment: and pct_total  I want the total percentage of "yes" in both province a and b as in there is 2 yes and 2 no overall_percentage of yes is 50% and overall percentable of no is 50%

Comment: @MaxMiak - Do you need the result in a data frame, or is a tabular output acceptable? If tabular output is OK, I'll post an answer with `tables::tabular()` this evening US hours.

Comment: I prefer data frame but if you give output in tabular is also okay i just want to see the logic Thank you in advance

Comment: @MaxMiak - see updated answer. The tricky part is the fact that the output requires both row and column percentages.